# Spark extraction and transformation on unstructured files

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I had a folder containing many sales text files in my local directory. Let's take an example of 2 text files:

Text File 1:

```
Sales Details
20161120


Sales Person: John

Code    Product     Quantity    Price
A0001   Product1    20          15.90
A0003   Product3    13          23.80
```

Text File 2:

```
Sales Details
20161130


Sales Person: Alicia

Code    Product     Quantity    Price
A0007   Product7    342         79.50
A0008   Product8    55          432.80
A0009   Product9    100         134.30
```

I had used Flume to stream the files into HDFS. All these small files are combined into one big file in HDFS. When I were to perform extract and transform on these files using Spark, I met some problem that need to seek advise from all of you here.

Based on the above 2 files, it will combined into one file in HDFS. I use Spark to read text file from HDFS as the following:

```
lines = spark.read.text('/user/tester/sales')
```

How do I split **lines** into two sales detail and then extract the information out for each sales person? My end goal is to extract information out and put it in Hive table with the following strucuture:

```
Date     SalesPerson     Code     Product     Quantity    Price
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file structure is not very handy to deal with but you can always use regular expressions with spark's `wholeTextFiles` to rewrite them to tabular format. See this pyspark code as example:

```
import re

def extract_sales(file):
    for line in file[1].split("\n"):
        if re.match('\d{8}', line.strip()):
            date = line.strip()
        if re.search('^Sales Person', line):
            person = re.match("^Sales Person: (.*)", line).group(1)
        if re.search('^A00', line):
            yield [date, person] + re.split('\s+', line)

raw_data = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles('sales/')
raw_data.flatMap(extract_sales) \
    .toDF(['Date', 'SalesPerson', 'Code', 'Product', 'Quantity', 'Price']).show()

+--------+-----------+-----+--------+--------+------+
|    Date|SalesPerson| Code| Product|Quantity| Price|
+--------+-----------+-----+--------+--------+------+
|20161120|       John|A0001|Product1|      20| 15.90|
|20161120|       John|A0003|Product3|      13| 23.80|
|20161130|     Alicia|A0007|Product7|     342| 79.50|
|20161130|     Alicia|A0008|Product8|      55|432.80|
|20161130|     Alicia|A0009|Product9|     100|134.30|
+--------+-----------+-----+--------+--------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks so much Mariusz !!! It helps me to get the idea on how to process it. By using the user defined function, when we are running the spark application, it will still leverage on spark engine instead of local python processing right?

Comment: Yes, sure. The function will be executed on cluster nodes, but to achieve parallelism you should have more than one big file on your input directory.

Comment: Ok... By the way, is it better performance for us to use "wholeTextFiles" compare to "text"?

Comment: Unstructured files like yours (with records spanning to multiple lines) cannot be parsed after reading them by `spark.read.text` or `sc.textFile`.

Comment: Ok, understood. Thanks a lot Mariusz :)

Comment: Hi Mariusz, I am currently facing another issue. If i have the 2 files like above but file 1(Sales Person: John) is very big while file 2 (Sales Person: Alicia) is smaller size. When i stream the file into HDFS, it become 2 files. File 1 (Sales Person: John) will spread across two files in HDFS. In this, when i am using the above pyspark code to run, the records for John in HDFS file 2 will be lost. Any opinion on how to handle this scenario?

Comment: How do you upload files do HDFS? Even big files should not be splitted.

Comment: Hi Mariusz, I am using Flume to stream in all the files....When i am using HDFS sink, it only can roll by size or transaction count. In my case, i am rolling the file by size. So it happens to be same file but split into two files in HDFS. I am not sure what other tools to use to automate the streaming part so that the file is not split to different files?

Comment: Just increase file size limit in flume - set it higher than expected one person sales.